# How do I install and run TnT (Trigrams 'n' Tags) in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nlp, pos-tagger

I downloaded the [TnT Part-of-Speech Tagger](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/tnt/) and want to use it on Ubuntu. I have been following the instructions in the [manual](http://www.coli.uni-saarland.de/~thorsten/publications/Brants-TR-TnT.pdf) (setting the path, environment variables) however when I finally type a command, say **tnt-para *option filename***, I get the error "**tnt-para: command not found**".

What could be the cause for this? Is there anything else I need to do apart from the first steps: changing path and environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

The error means `tnt-para` is not in your `PATH`. Try to `cd` to the directory where the `tnt-para` file is and run it like this:

```
./tnt-para option filename
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls`?

Comment: the output is:
doc           License.ps  scripts  tnt-diff  tnt-token
License.html  models      tnt      tnt-para  tnt-wc

Comment: Did you put the `./` in front of `tnt-para`? If you did and still get the same error I'm sorry but I don't know what's going on.

Comment: yes i did! No worries, thanks for the help though :)